# Які українські слова, які описують дуже специфічну ситуацію чи стан, не мають відповідних аналогів в інших мовах?

Tags: значення-слів

Часто зустрічаю публікації зі списками іншомовних слів, які описують *дуже специфічну ситуацію чи стан* і не мають аналогів чи коротких перекладів (не потрібно плутати з [мемами](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC)). Для перекладу таких слів використовують детальний опис.

Прикладами таких слів можуть бути:

> **Ареодярекпут** (одна з мов ескімосів) - обмін дружинами на кілька днів, в першу чергу, для прибирання.
>
> **Баккушан** (з японської) - дівчина, яка виглядає ззаду шикарно, але виявляється страшненькою спереду.
>
> **Куалункуізмо** (з італійської) - стан, коли ти настільки втомився від
>   того, що відбувається в політиці і суспільстві, що тобі вже немає ні
>   до чого справи.
>
> **Махж** (з перської) - прекрасно виглядати після
>   перенесеної хвороби.
>
> **Панапоо** (з гавайської) - чесати голову, згадуючи щось.
>
> **Сендула** (лунда,
>   одна з мов Замбії) - наштовхнутися в лісі на мертву тварину і
>   зметикувати, що лев або леопард, можливо, ще десь поблизу.
>
> **Уліккесбілен** (з датської) - автомобіль, який постійно потрапляє в аварії або
>   ламається.
>
> **Myötähäpeä**, мюйотяхяпе (з фінської) - почуття сорому, яке відчувається за безглузді і дурні вчинки інших (відомо також, як `іспанський сором`).

Цікаво почути, чи є щось схоже в українській мові?

Особисто я можу згадати тільки слово `майдан` (а також антонім `антимайдан`) в [контексті](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maidan) протестів: `The Orange Revolution protests that took place in Kiev’s Maidan in 2004–05; the Euromaidan protests of 2013–14; the protest movement associated with the 2014 Ukrainian Revolution`. Зрозуміло, що англійський переклад `square` не відповідає тому значенню, що вкладають в нього українці.

Comment: Проголосував за закриття. По-перше, для правильної відповіді, треба знати всі мови. По-друге, це знову ж таки не питання, на яке існує одна правильна відповідь.
Ну а щодо самого питання: "борщ" і "сало", здається, не перекладають, а транслітерують, відповідно, не мають аналогів.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, звісно, проголосувати за закриття є вашим правом. Проте є багато питань, особливо тих, що стосуються мови, на які немає "правильної" відповіді. Тому цікаво почути різні думки та обговорити "доцільні" варіанти. Щодо цього питання, то я не згоден, що потрібно знати всі мови. Достатньо добре знати українську мову і орієнтуватись в історичних подіях, прецедентах. Сало та борщ, очевидно, не підходять, оскільки вони не вписуються в "дуже специфічну ситуацію чи стан". Я розглядаю цей сайт як можливість глибоко розібратись в аспектах мови, а не лише як місце для тривіальних питань.

Comment: @sashaeve, наприклад "дивограй". Зараз широко вживане слово. Тлумачення не знайшла в словниках. Я б, мабуть, описала як "яскраве, барвисте, феєричне розмаїття"

Comment: пропоную також розглянути розповсюдженність явища яке у нас назвається [ОДОРО́БЛО](http://sum.in.ua/s/odoroblo)

Comment: @Chizh а ще  [ПОСИДЕ́НЬКИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/posydenjky)

Comment: Думаю, "кумівство" теж підходить.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55147/discussion-on-question-by-sashaeve-------).