# Чи є слово "маршрутка" усталеним та самостійним?

Tags: переклад, етимологія, значення-слів

Немає сумнівів у тому, що слово *маршрутка* широко розповсюджене, але, на мій погляд, воно не є офіційним, оскільки походить від *маршрутне таксі*, але в той же час варто зазначити, що це вже давно не таксі, а радше приватний маршрутний автобус. Тому постає питання, чи досі *маршрутка* еквівалентне *маршрутному таксі*, або це вже самостійний термін, що означає розбиту тарадайку з водієм, що однією рукою кермує, а іншою дає здачу? Чи доречно досі вживати в діловій мові *маршрутне таксі*, чи варто використовувати *маршрутка*? Як правильно перекладати слово *маршрутка* на інші мови? За правилами транслітерації, або як словосполучення "таксі, що їздить за певним маршрутом"?

UPD:
Стосовно того, чи було *маршрутне таксі* колись *таксі* взагалі. Я вважаю, що так. З самого початку існування *маршрутного таксі*:
- оплата проїзду здійснювалась при виході (як у *таксі*);
- при перевезенні використовувались тільки сидячі місця (як у *таксі*);
- зупинка на вихід здійснювалась на вимогу пасажирів у довільному місці, якщо це не суперечить правилам дорожнього руху (як у *таксі*).

Comment: Маршрутка - хороший кандидат для списку слів, що не мають точного аналогу в інших не-слов'янських мовах http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/383/326

Comment: Взагалі-то метро - це теж скорочення від метрополітен, і навіть спочатку "метро" було словом чоловічого роду.

Comment: [Ось приклад](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/how-much-to-pay-for-hiring-marshrutka-in-ukraine) того, наскільки цей термін збиває з пантелику іноземців

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Таксі тому й маршрутне, що в нього є маршрут, тому не можна сказати, що *це вже не таксі*, бо воно ніколи не було *таксі*.
2. [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/f/marshrutka) каже, що це розмовне слово:

   > жін., розм. Вид громадського транспорту — перев. мікроавтобус, що курсує за міським або міжміським маршрутом; маршрутне таксі.

   Той же [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ustalenyj) каже, що усталений:

   > у знач. прикм. Сталий, стійкий, який закріпився у певній формі.

   Можемо стверджувати, що слово закріпилося в мові, бо ним користуються всі, і немає людини, яка б його не знала.
3. Переклад на англійську: *Minibus*

   [Wikipedia for Minibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minibus)

   [Google for Minibus](https://www.google.co.il/search?client=opera&biw=1366&bih=659&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=minibus&oq=minibus&gs_l=img.3...925.925.0.1010.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.COOxnYbynCM)

   [UK government for Minibus](https://www.gov.uk/driving-a-minibus)

   Звісно, що це не відображає сенсу, бо нічого не каже про маршрут, але якщо вже обирати поміж *bus* і *minibus*, то, звісно, друге, бо за конструкцією саме воно найближче до *маршрутки*.
4. Оцей відповідник найточніше передає сутність *маршрутного таксі*: Shared taxi

   [Wikipedia for Shared taxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share_taxi)

Comment: *minibus* = *бусик* ? :)

Comment: @P.Vovk, тільки не `shareD`, а `share`.

Comment: @Gluttton там є обидві форми, і мені більше подобається друга. Посилання на вікіпедію до послуг користувачок, кожна нехай обирає, що їй ближче.

Comment: Shared taxi article has an entry for [Marshrutka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share_taxi#Marshrutka).

Answer (score 1):

На інші мови значно простіше і зручніше перекладати це як автобус "BUS".
Я не зустрічався з терміном маршрутка в Європі.
А те, що ми звемо маршруткою прийнято називати автобусом.

Comment: Прийнято називати Minibus.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian.SE. На жаль, ця відповідь не відповідає критеріям якості: вона містить суб'єктивну і нічим не підтверджену думку автора, і більш нічого. Але ви можете відредагувати [edit](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/posts/520/edit) відповідь, додавши до неї пояснення, посилання на поважні джерела тощо. Погляньте, як на цьому сайті оформлені інші відповіді, які набрали позитивних голосів.

Comment: @P.Vovk, ніколи не чув від іноземців minibus. А наші маршрутки вони теж ніколи не перекладають. Хоча ваші посилання говорять про певну відповідність.